# Array in Cake PHP

Tags: arrays, cakephp

Currently I have this Array:

```
Array
(
  [0]=>Array
             (
                 [name]=> Name 1
             )
  [1]=>Array
             (
                 [name]=> Name 2
             )
)
```

How can I manipulate this array to display like this

```
Array(
      [0] =>Name 1
      [1] =>Name 2
      )
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but are you getting that array from a `find` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Set` class:

```
Set::extract('/name', $data);
```